# TypeError: Argument given by name ('axis') and position (2)

Tags: python, typeerror

Im new on python world and I got the error trying to do this:

```
d_negative = (np.ones((Nsamples, 1), dtype=int))*-1
d_positive = np.ones((Nsamples, 1), dtype=int)
d = np.concatenate(d_negative, d_positive, axis=1)
```

Nsamples = 100

I would like to create a 200 itens array of positive and negative ones. starting with the negatives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also simply try to append two arrays like so

```
plus_one = np.ones(100)
minus_one = np.ones(100)*(-1)
minus_plus = np.append(minus_one,plus_one)
```

Comment: Good, if I change the axis for 0 (or dont mention it), it works!
But why I cant use concatenate?

Comment: it does work as well, try adding parenthesis like so  
d = np.concatenate((d_negative, d_positive)). Look at the definition of this function, numpy.concatenate((a1, a2, ...), axis=0, out=None), is initialized with the argument arrays a1,a2,... with parenthesis around them.